# Python .extend splitting Characters unnecessarily

Tags: python, arrays, loops, python-3.x, split

```
colourImgArray = []
                    sizeList = soup.find('table', {'class' :'table-sku'})
                    for sizeTD in sizeList.findAll('td', {'class' :'name'}):
                        for sized in sizeTD.findAll("span"):
                             size = str(sized['title'])
                             colourImgArray.extend(size)
```

When i try print sized inside the loop, i get a work together(2+ chinese characters) BUT once i do extend to it, each character is split.

How do i make it not split because it's together after all.

Comment: Including example data with the code will help analyze your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `append`, not `extend`!

```
>>> colourImgArray = []
>>> sized = 'sometitle'
>>> colourImgArray.extend(sized)
>>> colourImgArray
['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'i', 't', 'l', 'e']
```

Extend want iterable as argument so above call to extend with string is equal to calling `colourImgArray.extend(list(sized))` - string becomes iterable (each char is element of list):

```
>>> colourImgArray = []
>>> colourImgArray.extend(list(sized))
>>> colourImgArray
['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'i', 't', 'l', 'e']
```

You can use extend anyway by creating iterable with one element only to append whole string:

```
>>> colourImgArray.extend([sized])
>>> colourImgArray
['sometitle']
```

And `append` just did what it should:

```
>>> colourImgArray = []
>>> colourImgArray.append(sized)
>>> colourImgArray
['sometitle']
```

Answer (score 3):

`list.extend` takes any sequence, and a string is a sequence of characters. You want either

```
colourImgArray.extend([size])
```

or

```
colourImgArray.append(size)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you pass a value to extend, it does split

For eg:-

a = [other values]

a.extend('1-00')

Output:

a = ['1','-','0','0',other values]

Try passing a list to extend method

a = [other values]

a.extend(['1-00'])

Output:

a = ['1-00', other values]

> > > colorImgArray = []
> > >
> > > sized='sometitle'
> > >
> > > colorImgArray.extend(sized)
> > >
> > > colorImgArray

['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'i', 't', 'l', 'e']

> > > colorImgArray.extend([sized])
> > >
> > > colorImgArray

['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'i', 't', 'l', 'e', 'sometitle']

Hope it helps!